# How to correctly pull data from couchbase? Data stored incorrectly

Tags: r, json, couchbase, httr

I am trying to pull in some data that is stored in couchbase. The data is pulled in but it shows up as the following after it is saved.

After saving the query and correctly connecting to the source, I run the following code

```
req <- httr::POST(cbServer, httr::add_headers("Content-Type" = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8"), body = paste("statement=", query, "&creds=", creds));

res <- fromJSON(httr::content(req, "text"))

ResResults <- res$results
```

Creds and query are the variable name for my credentials and query that i am running.

The print out of ResResults shows the following.

```
               test

1   <data.frame [10 × 36]>          
2   <data.frame [10 × 36]>          
3   <data.frame [10 × 36]>          
4   <data.frame [10 × 36]>
```

How to I get this stored as an actual table or pull in the data correctly so it shows properly. Ideally, I would have all the information in one dataframe with all of the data.

I have attempted to get the data out of the frame, and to re-save it as one by running the following

```
r <- ResResults$test
```

which gives this error:

```
Error in View : 'names' attribute [1] must be the same length as the vector [0]
```

Comment: **Error in handle_url(handle, url, ...) : object 'cbServer' not found** Please make your question reproducible.

Comment: @NelsonGon due to sensitivity, I cannot. I guess the proper question is, how do I get the data frames out of a data frame and save it as one dataframe. I will edit the question to show the codes I have run

Comment: Honestly I personally find it easier to understand a problem by looking at the data. Without that, anything I may say may be a lie. Hopefully someone else helps you solve the issue.

Comment: To clarify: is the output from `test` (i.e. `<data.frame [10 × 36]> ` what R actually returns or is this just to mask your data?